# cant show data in table using mobx state tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx

I am getting the following error when trying to pass data to material ui table, the table isnt displayed and it crash. Cannot modify '', the object is protected and can only be modified by using an action.
im using typescript and mobx state tree

```
setTreasurers: flow(function* () {
    return self.treasurerData =  yield getAllTreasurers();
})



  var showTreasurerData = userStore.getTreasurerData

 const cloneSheeps = [...showTreasurerData];
return (
    <div>
      <MaterialTable
        title="Tesoreros"
        columns={[
          { title: "Email", field: "email" },
          { title: "Cuit", field: "cuit" },

          {
            title: "Verificado",
            field: "verified",
          },
        ]}
   
         data={cloneSheeps} 
      options={{
        sorting: true,
        actionsColumnIndex: -1
      }}
      localization={
        { header: { actions: 'Acciones' } }
      }

        actions={
          [
            {
              position: "auto",
              icon: "done",
              tooltip: "Enable User",
              onClick: (event, user) => {
                var isVerified = true;
                ManageTreasurerVerification(user, isVerified)
              },
            },
            {
              icon: "cancel",
              tooltip: "Disable User",
              onClick: (event, user) => {
                var isVerified = false;
                ManageTreasurerVerification(user, isVerified)
              },
            },
          ]}
    
        
      />
```

Comment: You can try `toJs(showTreasurerData)` and pass it into the table like that. `toJs` is MobX function, you would need to import it

Comment: Please improve the formatting